# Regex that matches a list of comma separated items in any order

Tags: regex

I have three "Clue texts" that say:

```
SomeClue=someText
AnotherClue=somethingElse
YetAnotherClue=moreText
```

I need to parse a string and see if it contains exactly these 3 texts, separated by a comma. No Clue Text contains any comma.
The problem is, they can be in any order and they must be the only clues in the string.

Matches:

```
SomeClue=someText,AnotherClue=somethingElse,YetAnotherClue=moreText
SomeClue=someText,YetAnotherClue=moreText,AnotherClue=somethingElse
AnotherClue=somethingElse,SomeClue=someText,YetAnotherClue=moreText
YetAnotherClue=moreText,SomeClue=someText,AnotherClue=somethingElse
```

Non-Matches:

```
    SomeClue=someText,AnotherClue=somethingElse,YetAnotherClue=moreText,
    SomeClue=someText,YetAnotherClue=moreText,,AnotherClue=somethingElse
    ,AnotherClue=somethingElse,SomeClue=someText,YetAnotherClue=moreText
    YetAnotherClue=moreText,SomeClue=someText,AnotherClue=somethingElse,UselessText
    YetAnotherClue=moreText,SomeClue=someText,AnotherClue=somethingElse,AClueThatIDontWant=wrongwrongwrong
```

Putting togheter what I found on other posts, I have:

```
(?=.*SomeClue=someText($|,))(?=.*AnotherClue=somethingElse($|,))(?=.*YetAnotherClue=moreText($|,))
```

This works as far as Clues and their order are concerned.
Unfortunately, I can't find a way to avoid adding a comma and then some stupid text at the end.

My real case has somewhat more complicated Clue Texts, because each of them is a small regex, but I am pretty sure once I know how to handle commas, the rest will be easy.

Comment: Are you after `^(SomeClue=someText|AnotherClue=somethingElse|YetAnotherClue=moreText),(?1),(?1)$` ? Please try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yo7tER/1/).

Comment: It seems to work correctly, thank you! It seems I have to add a library that allows for the (?1) construct that I don't know and it has to do with recursion. Right? (I am using c#)

Comment: You are welcome @Johannes. Yes you are correct, its a recursion pattern. Note that you do not actually need recursion, you can just use [^(?:SomeClue=someText|AnotherClue=somethingElse|YetAnotherClue=moreText),(?:SomeClue=someText|AnotherClue=somethingElse|YetAnotherClue=moreText),(?:SomeClue=someText|AnotherClue=somethingElse|YetAnotherClue=moreText)$](https://regex101.com/r/keRUl2/1/). I just suggested recursion for a more concise pattern. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Bear in mind that that pattern allows `SomeClue=someText,SomeClue=someText,SomeClue=someText`. Do you want `SomeClue,AnotherClue,YetAnotherClue` to only occur once?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off with a stronger tool than regexes (and I genuinely love regular expressions).  Regexes aren't good with needing supplementary memory, which is what you have here: you need exactly these 3, but they can come in any order.

In principle, you could write a regex for each of the 6 permutations.  But that would never scale.  You ought to use something with parsing power.

I suggest writing a verification function in your favorite scripting language, made up of underlying string functions.

In basic Python, you could do (for instance)

```
ref = set(['SomeClue=someText', 'AnotherClue=somethingElse', 'YetAnotherClue=moreText'])

def ismatch(myline):
  splt = myline.split(',')
  return ref == set(splt)
```

You can tweak that as necessary, of course.  Note that this nearly-complete solution is not really longer, and much more readable, than any regex would be.